# Referring to a pure virtual method

Tags: python, polymorphism, late-binding, dynamic-dispatch

I am probably missing something obvious here. I have a simple class hierarchy that looks roughly like this:

```py
class Any:
    def op2_additive_add(self, other: 'Any') -> 'Any':
        raise NotImplementedError

    def op2_multiplicative_multiply(self, other: 'Any') -> 'Any':
        raise NotImplementedError

    def op2_exponential_power(self, other: 'Any') -> 'Any':
        raise NotImplementedError

    # A dozen of similar methods not shown

class Rational(Any):
    def op2_additive_add(self, other: 'Any') -> 'Rational':
        pass    # Implementation not shown

    def op2_multiplicative_multiply(self, other: 'Any') -> 'Rational':
        pass    # Implementation not shown

    def op2_exponential_power(self, other: 'Any') -> 'Rational':
        pass    # Implementation not shown

class Set(Any):
    def op2_additive_add(self, other: 'Any') -> 'Set':
        pass    # Implementation not shown

    def op2_multiplicative_multiply(self, other: 'Any') -> 'Set':
        pass    # Implementation not shown

    def op2_exponential_power(self, other: 'Any') -> 'Set':
        pass    # Implementation not shown

# Half a dozen of similar derived types not shown.
```

I am implementing a dispatcher class that is supposed to choose the requested operation on two operands while not knowing their types, and pass a reference to the correct method onwards to an executor. Roughly like this (the code below will not work):

```py
def select_operator(selector) -> typing.Callable[[Any, Any], Any]:
    if selector.such_and_such():
        return Any.op2_additive_add
    elif selector.so_and_so():
        return Any.op2_exponential_power
    # And so on
```

The above code will not work because an attempt to invoke a returned unbound method will bypass the dynamic dispatch; i.e. `select_operator(selector)(foo, bar)` will always throw a `NotImplementedError`.

The best solution I could come up with so far is roughly like this, and it is not pretty:

```py
def select_operator(selector) -> str:
    if selector.such_and_such():
        return Any.op2_additive_add.__name__
    elif selector.so_and_so():
        return Any.op2_exponential_power.__name__
    # And so on

method_name = select_operator(selector)
getattr(foo, method_name)(bar)
```

TL;DR: How do I delay the dynamic dispatch process until after I took a reference to a method?

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to push Python through a Java/C#/C++ shaped hole. What are you actually trying to achieve here? What is your expected output?

Comment: I am building an interpreter of a simple DSL. It performs basic data manipulations, and the result is then used for code generation (C++/Python/Rust/C and possibly other languages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will be more suitable?

```
class Any:
    def select_and_do_op(self, selector, other):
        if selector.such_and_such():
            return self.op2_additive_add.(other)
        elif selector.so_and_so():
            return self.op2_exponential_power(other)
    ...

foo.select_and_do_op(selector, bar)
```

**UPDATE**

One another solution:

```
def select_operator(selector):
    if selector.such_and_such():
        return lambda foo, bar: foo.op2_additive_add(bar)
    elif selector.so_and_so():
        return lambda foo, bar: foo.op2_exponential_power(bar)
    ...

operator = select_operator(selector)
result = operator(foo, bar)
```

Comment: Eh, it works, but the huge disadvantage here is that it introduces an undesirable coupling between well-isolated components of the application. The `Any` class is unaware of the operator selection logic and I don't want to change that.

Comment: Updated my answer, second solution doesn't require modification of `Any` class and its subclasses.

Comment: Indeed. Looks like a lot of boilerplate, but I can deal with that.

Comment: So I ended up defining a set of standalone functions of the form `def op2_bitwise_or(left: 'Any', right: 'Any') -> 'Any':` that merely invoke the corresponding methods. Ugly but it certainly works and I'm yet to find a better solution. Thank you for the idea!

Comment: Glad to help you. Also if you will find some better solution that can be interesting and helpful for others, you can post it as an answer here.